# Is it safe to intermingle '/' and '\' for directory path in Windows Programming?

Tags: windows, directory

I happen to have a directory path such as "c:\a\b/c/d\e", but it works fine with boost library.

I don't know if it's OK to intermingle '\' and '/' in Windows. Is it allowed in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) says it's OK to use forward slashes in Windows API functions, they are converted to backslashes before anything is done.

I imagine the C runtime also does this (although I can't find a reference right now), so you should be OK no matter what file-related function you call.